# Kivy progress bar value updates, but progress bar does not

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a ProgressBar in my kivy app. I believe I need to use `Clock.create_trigger` to ensure the progress bar updates from inside of a loop.

I've attempted to adapt the solutions from [Progress bar in kivy can't update using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186990/progress-bar-in-kivy-cant-update-using-loop) and [Kivy How can i create time counter with progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990499/kivy-how-can-i-create-time-counter-with-progressbar) for my solution, however, the bar still does not update until the very end.

The following code is a watered-down version for reproducibility purposes.

**ProgressBar Class**

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar


class MyProgressBar(ProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # self.update_bar_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(self.update_bar)
        self.update_bar_trigger = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.update_bar(), 1)

    def update_bar(self, step):
        if self.value <= 100:
            self.value += step
            self.update_bar_trigger()
```

**Main class:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from MyProgressBar import MyProgressBar

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('style.kv')


class Main_app(BoxLayout):
    # Progress bars
    loading_pb = MyProgressBar()

    def dummy(self):
        pb_increment = 10

        for i in range(10):
            time.sleep(2)
            self.loading_pb.update_bar(pb_increment)
            print(self.loading_pb.value)


class Stacked(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        Window.size = (1000, 700)

        return Main_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Stacked().run()
```

**KV File**

```
<Main_app>:
    loading_pb: load_pb

    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        MyProgressBar:
            id: load_pb
            value: 0
            min: 0
            max: 100

        Button:
            text: 'Start Progress Bar'
            on_press:
                root.dummy()
```

This example shows loading_pb.value changing as the code loops through after the button is clicked.

**ProgressBar.value printed output**

```
10.0
20.0
30.0
40.0
50.0
60.0
70.0
80.0
90.0
100.0
```

**Problem**
The progress bar *value* does seem to increment as expected, but the actual progress bar does not change until all at once, at the end of the loop.

[image: gif of progress bar not updating]

**Related**

- [Can't get kivy progress bar to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019432/cant-get-kivy-progress-bar-to-update)
- [Progress bar in kivy can't update using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52186990/progress-bar-in-kivy-cant-update-using-loop)
- [Kivy How can i create time counter with progressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56990499/kivy-how-can-i-create-time-counter-with-progressbar)
- [How to update progressbar using Clock Object with Multithreading in kivy-python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35111229/how-to-update-progressbar-using-clock-object-with-multithreading-in-kivy-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.loading_pb.update_bar(pb_increment)
        print(self.loading_pb.value)
```

This bit of code blocks the gui until it returns, so none of the normal gui drawing takes place. Instead, use `Clock.schedule_interval` and/or `Clock.schedule_once` to schedule each iteration of the loop. These insert the function call into kivy's own eventloop, and avoid blocking that loop.